# Centralized vs Distributed Version Control on Oracle Right Now

Tags: oracle, git, svn

I have been tasked with setting up some type of version control for our development server files location. We current use Oracle's Service Cloud called "Right Now". It holds our dev/staging/prod environments for multiple sites.

Basically I need to VC just the dev files.. and not have to carry a local repo. Is this possible? The reason being for no local is there are just tooo many sites to download all locally. I want to open the files in Sublime from the dev server, make changes, save them, then at some point create a commit regarding the files I changed since the last commit. How can this be done.

I would love to use git, but this requires a local repo as far as I can tell. What about SVN? Could this do it? Your suggestions and resource links are appreciated.

~ WB

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Oracle's "Right Now" product so I may be missing something important here. Putting this "Right Now" aside, I can say that Apache Subversion can be a good match for your requirements.

1. With Subversion you don't need to download the whole repository as you need with Git. Subversion's [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) which you need to [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) is much less in size than the whole repository in Git because is represents a particular snapshot of the repository's state in time (it does not contain the whole repo history as in Git).
2. You can checkout only a part of a repository. E.g. if a repository contains multiple projects, you can choose which ones to checkout.
3. Using [sparse directories / shallow checkouts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) can help you to minimize the size of the working copy by specifying only those modules you require to operate on.